# ksqlDB error when deserilaizing jeager spans from protobuf

Tags: confluent-schema-registry, ksqldb, jaeger

I am trying to get ksqlDB to deserialize protobuf messages with not much success I am afraid.

More specifically, I have Jaeger spans published to a Kafka broker by Jaeger Collector and have successfully register the [Jaeger protobuf schema model](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-idl/blob/05fe64e9c305526901f70ff692030b388787e388/proto/api_v2/model.proto) with schema registry under /subjects/jaeger-spans-value/ route and the schema string is properly escaped.

The Collector is configured to publish Kafka: `KAFKA_PRODUCER_ENCODING: 'protobuf'`, while spans generated by the HotROD app are published directly to the Collector over HTTP at `jaeger-collector:14268/api/traces`.

KsqlDB always returns a deserialization error when I am trying to register any stream against that topic:

`ERROR {"type":0,"deserializationError":{"target":"value","errorMessage":"Error deserializing message from topic: jaeger-spans","recordB64":null,"cause":["Failed to deserialize data for topic jaeger-spans to Protobuf: ","Error deserializing Protobuf message for id -1","Unknown magic byte!"],"topic":"jaeger-spans"},"recordProcessingError":null,"productionError":null,"serializationError":null,"kafkaStreamsThreadError":null} (processing.transient_STR_SPANS_MODEL_8922992258591230941.KsqlTopic.Source.deserializer:44)`

It is worth noting that all this are running inside a docker compose stack, but I have tested the same setup with JSON as the Jaeger span encoding format and works like a dream. ksqlDB successfully communicates with the schema registry.

Any ideas/feedback would be highly appreciated.

~GS